# How to Download Signed URL from Google Could Bucket Storage

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've get a signed url which is valid for 10minutes...

such as `http://..my...signed...url..here.com/blahblahblah`

here is my code

```js
let response = await axios.get(url ?? "", {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
if(response.status !== 200){
    return;
}
console.log(response.data);
```

But instead of the data downloading, it shows this in the network log

[image]

I just want the `response.data` to have the full contents of the file store in it.

Note: This is from testing on localhost

Comment: It says "CORS error" – see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors

Answer (score 0):

issue found, had to do with cors, need to set the cors access stuff for google could storage bucket..

#### cors-data.json

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

`gsutil cors set cors-data.json gs://BUCKET_NAME`